# How to save DATE in Oracle database

Tags: php, oracle, activerecord, yii2

I am trying to save data in a table in oracle db. One of the columns in this table is a RESULT_DUE_DATE of type DATE. I am working with the yii2 framework. When trying to insert data in the table, it's not saving.
However, when I ommit the RESULT_DUE_DATE column and just insert the rest of the data, the data is saved successfully. I have tried catching any exceptions but none is shown. How do I save the date?

Here is part of my db config file:

```
  'on afterOpen' => function ($event) {
        $event->sender->createCommand("ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD-MON-YYYY'")->execute();
    },
```

Part of my model is as shown:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['ASSESSMENT_TYPE_ID', 'WEIGHT'], 'integer'],
        [['MARKSHEET_ID'], 'string', 'max' => 60],
        [['RESULT_DUE_DATE'], 'string'],
    ];
}
```

Part of my controller is as shown:

```
  // action to save the coursework 
  public function actionSaveCoursework(){
        $marksheetDefPost = Yii::$app->request->post('MarksheetDef');
        $courseworkPost = Yii::$app->request->post('CourseWorkAssessment');
        $cwModel = new CourseWorkAssessment();

        $transact = Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
        try{
            $cwModel->MARKSHEET_ID = $marksheetDefPost['MRKSHEET_ID'];
            $cwModel->ASSESSMENT_TYPE_ID = $courseworkPost['ASSESSMENT_TYPE_ID'];
            $cwModel->WEIGHT = $courseworkPost['WEIGHT'];


            // Save the result due date
            $cwModel->RESULT_DUE_DATE = $this->getSaveDate($courseworkPost['RESULT_DUE_DATE']);


            $id = $cwModel->save();
            $transact->commit();
            return $this->redirect(['index']);   
  
        }catch(Exception $ex){
            $transact->rollBack();
            return $this->redirect(['index']);     
        }
    }



    /**
     * Format the date before saving 
     * 
     * @param string $date user provided
     * @param string $format desired format
     * 
     * @return string corectly formated date
     */
    private function getSaveDate($date, $format = "d-M-Y"){
        $time = strtotime($date);
        return date($format, $time);
    }
```

Comment: I've never even heard of yii2,  but it looks to me that your getSaveDAte function is returning a date with time, but your nls_date_format (upon which an oracle to_date conversion will depend, only accounts for the date portion.

Comment: @EdStevens my getSaveDate() method returns date as eg 17-Nov-2020

Comment: check if $cwModel->errors is returning anything after calling save method when trying to save date.

Comment: @AkshayVanjare I noticed that the my date validaion rule was wrong. I corrected that and it's working now.